# To move 3d chart Highcharts via mobile?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working at this charts:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable

But I have noticed that with mobile (phone or tablet) is impossible to move (with thouch) the charts.

I have also used this:

```
tooltip: {         
    followTouchMove: true
}
```

Maybe is impossible with all phones or my iPhone (Safari) doesn't support this option?

Comment: Same experience on Chrome for Android.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with normalization, so you need modify lines, which refers to pageX/pageY positions.

```
$(chart.container).bind('mousedown.hc touchstart.hc', function (e) {
    e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);

    var originalEvent = e.originalEvent || e,
        posX = originalEvent.changedTouches ? originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
        posY = originalEvent.changedTouches ? originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY,
        alpha = chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha,
        beta = chart.options.chart.options3d.beta,
        newAlpha,
        newBeta,
        sensitivity = 5; // lower is more sensitive

    $(document).bind({
        'mousemove.hc touchmove.hc': function (e) {
            // Run beta
            var originalEvent = e.originalEvent || e,
                pageX = originalEvent.changedTouches ? originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
                pageY = originalEvent.changedTouches ? originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;


            newBeta = beta + (posX - pageX) / sensitivity;
            newBeta = Math.min(100, Math.max(-100, newBeta));
            chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = newBeta;

            // Run alpha
            newAlpha = alpha + (pageY - posY) / sensitivity;
            newAlpha = Math.min(100, Math.max(-100, newAlpha));
            chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha = newAlpha;

            chart.redraw(false);
        },
            'mouseup touchend': function () {
            $(document).unbind('.hc');
        }
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L8o0pt6j/7/